# How to set rules in firebase in react native

Tags: react-native

My Question is how to create rules for real time database in firebase to only edit the specific user for the specific field. Like we do with PHP and Mysql easly..
What I mean to say is that when someone makes an account Using my react native app there should be a conversation and also a users list created already in the firebase store with the rules set that only the uid == the_id_in_the_databse can erase or edit that...
Waiting for your reply

Comment: would be nice to see your realtime database document structure and what you wanna do exactly.

Comment: Well currently I am using no rules in firebase as i am not doing it for production. but for practice. What i exactly wanna do is like we set rules in PHP and mysqli i.e: update `dummy-table` where user='user' and only that user has the access to use CRUD in that specific field or table. Hope you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: if its about updating/deleting only documents which are owned by the user, you should have a "createdby" field in the document and when doing an delete or update, you can create a rule like auth.uid = createdby. Is thats what you want?

Comment: yes thats what i want but I want it like when the user signup for first time there would a table of users and another table and a rule was created automatically without going in console of firebase.

Comment: you can create rules via API so that you can automate things.